# SQL copy data from to another table based on 2 matched column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, in same Database:
table1 & table2.

table1 columns = a, b, c, d &
table 2 columns = c, d, e, f

I am trying to UPDATE values a, b from e,f using:

```
UPDATE table1 as t1 
SET t1.a = t2.e, t1.b = t2.f
FROM table2 AS t2 
WHERE (t1.c=t2.c) AND (t1.d=t2.d);
```

Both matches are MUST. But its giving SQL Error. Any idea, what m doing wrong ?? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "But its giving SQL Error. " What error?

Comment: What's the error it returns ? And can you please update the structure and data of your table.

Comment: It simply says - SQL Syntax Error

Comment: @sgeddes Can u plz tell, where is its duplicate ??

Comment: @Anandjain SQL Syntax near 'FROM table2 AS t2 WHERE (t1.c=t2.c)

Comment: @luna.romania -- you need to `join` the tables together as in the accepted answer.  Your syntax is off for mysql. `update ... join ... set...`